# callback on background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, callback

I was wondering if it's possible to ensure that an android callback is handled on a background thread?

Specifically the listener I'm dealing with is a SurfaceTextureListener and I've tried calling setSurfaceTextureView using the post method of a HandlerThread.

However, the SurfaceTextureListener callbacks are called on the main thread. Any ideas how to go about this? Thanks!